# Android - View not showing when setting Layout Params

Tags: android, android-framelayout

in my Android app i'm defining the following layout which is working fine.

```
     <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/black">
        <com.test.zoom.ImageZoomView
            android:id="@+id/zoomview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <ZoomControls
            android:id="@+id/zoomControls"
            android:layout_width="130dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>
    </FrameLayout>
```

But when set the layout parameters on the FrameLayout the ZoomControls are gone.
Do you have a hint what i'm doing wrong?

```
    ViewTreeObserver viewTreeObserver = frame.getViewTreeObserver();
    if (viewTreeObserver.isAlive()) {
        viewTreeObserver.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                frame.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                frame.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(frame.getMeasuredWidth(), frame.getMeasuredWidth()));
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your ZoomControls is a child of FrameLayout. So if you remove the FrameLayout, all of its children(com.test.zoom.ImageZoomView & ZoomControls) will be removed as well.
Try to make your ZoomControl be indepent from FrameLayout, like this:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/black">
    <com.test.zoom.ImageZoomView
        android:id="@+id/zoomview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</FrameLayout>

<ZoomControls
        android:id="@+id/zoomControls"
        android:layout_width="130dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"/>
```

Comment: Well that would work, but i want the zoom controls to be within the FrameLayout on top of the image.